# Force killing a Cloud Dataflow job

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

When trying to enter the job info from GC web UI, it never opens but this kind of message is presented in the main jobs listing:

`A job with ID "2017-10-17_23_35_15-3310306527853724439" doesn't exist`

`gcloud dataflow jobs cancel` returns this kind of message (repeatedly):

```
Failed to cancel job [2017-10-17_23_35_15-3310306527853724439]: 
(882c3a8a1f6e0d10): Workflow modification failed. Causes: 
(19752e1d053cad56): Operation cancel not allowed for job 2017-10-
17_23_35_15-3310306527853724439. Job is not yet ready for canceling. 
Please retry in a few minutes.
```

Updating or deploying a new job with the same name doesn't work. So how to force kill the job?

Comment: Apologies for the delay in triaging this. Is the issue still happening? Could you try cancelling this job one more time and include a new error message if it's still failing?

Comment: All solved, status update was published for this.